# RStudioでファイルの保存ができません。

Tags: r, rstudio

今まで普通に使えていたのですが、突然Saveボタンを押すと以下の警告の画面が出て
ファイルを保存できなくなりました

ショートカットで保存しようとしても同様の現象が起こります。

さらに普通にコーディングしている最中にもこの画面が出てしまいます。

RStudioは最新のバージョンで、Rのversion 3.5.3となっています。

解決策のご教示お願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

Google ドライブ内のファイルを編集しようとしていないでしょうか？
Google ドライブとRStudioが競合してこのようなエラーが表示されることがあります。
同期を一時的にオフにする、または他のクラウドストレージサービスに移行する（少なくともDropboxでは同様のエラーはおきないようです）のが解決策になると思います。

参考：[Rstudio and Google Drive - RStudio IDE - RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-and-google-drive/693)

Comment: ありがとうございます。Googleドライブではなく、DropBoxで作業しており、もしかしたら同じく競合によるエラーなのかもしれません。リンク先も参考にさせていただきます